# Argument of type '{ name: string; email: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-query

I am using React Query with TypeScript.

Mutation:

```
   let mutation = useMutation((newUser) => {
      return signup(newUser)
   })
```

Submit function:

```
const onSignupSubmit = ({ name, email, password }: User) => {
      mutation.mutate(
          {
            name,
            email,
            password,
         }
      )
   }
```

Also this line giving me error:

```
mutation?.error?.response?.data?.field
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Take the [tour], read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

you need to define the type of the mutation function passed to `useMutation`:

```
let mutation = useMutation((newUser: User) => {
    return signup(newUser)
})
```

a shorter way would be to omit the arrow function and just do:

```
let mutation = useMutation(signup)
```